# Save scrcpy screen recording to another directory

Tags: android, screen-recording

Trying to save my screen recordings to another directory (E.g. logs folder).

```
 cmd = "scrcpy --no-display " + "--serial " + o + " --record " + o + ".mp4 -p " + str(sport)
```

Currently it is saved at the folder where i executed my test scripts.

I tried adding a /logs/xxx.mp4 but it didn't work and threw errors as shown below

> Failed to open output file and could not open recorder

Just wondering if scrcpy allows us to save the recordings in the directory that we specify.

Scrcpy: https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy

If not i will probably move the recordings using another command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use path such as logs/file.mp4 and not /logs/file.mp4

It will save it to ur specific directory.

```
cmd = "scrcpy --no-display " + "--serial " + o + " --record " + "logs/" + o + ".mp4 -p " + str(sport)
```